# General error mounting filesystems after upgrade from 10.04 to 12.04

Tags: boot, apt, mount, fstab, nfs

I updated My server from ubuntu 10.04 LT to 12.04 LT and I had couple of errors but it was completed without asking me to reboot. when I rebooted I had the following error: 
General error mounting filesystems.
A maintenance shell will now be started. 
CONTROL-D will terminate this shell and continue reboot the system.
I can see /dev/sda1 as read only, no chance of change it to rw. 
I tried the following
Boot on LiveUSB
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo chroot /mnt
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade
(no network)
then it try to update nfs-common nfs-kernel-server and I get dependency error and it fail. I use --purge to remove both and try again to install and i get same error. I ended up uninstalling both for now.
I also edited my /etc/fstab file and disconnected all but main HD and still get the same error. The strange thing is even after I edit fstab, it still try to mount what was in the original file (looking at mtab and using df). It behave as if fstab is unchanged! The original set up included 4 network raid systems and /dev/md0.
I also try to boot using older kernel and in recovery mode and I get same error.
Any advise how to successfully rescue the system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the update change the permission of /bin/mount and umount which prevented the system from booting properly. I booted from live CD and changed the permissions back and it booted fine this time with all updates! Problem solved!